# What is a "secret hat"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I clicked through to see what a hat was awarded for, means, etc. And it saya it is a secret hat. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means the reason it's awarded for is secret. You aren't supposed to know how to get it until you are awarded it.

Comment: I have been awarded them, but I don't know why.

Comment: @jdlugosz You can participate in the fun of figuring it out on your own *or* you can [cheat and look at the answers by the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats). Your choice. :)

Comment: I'm still trying on my last achieved one :-P ... (not that one I'm wearing currently)